# Animación en js, efecto de parpadeo

Tags: javascript, css

Pretendo pasar esta animacion de parpadeo de css a javascript(lo quiero activar desde javascript)

```
#formulario:hover{
       /*position: absolute;*/

  animation-name: parpadeo;
  animation-duration: 1s;
  animation-timing-function: linear;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;

  -webkit-animation-name:parpadeo;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 1s;
  -webkit-animation-timing-function: linear;
  -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}

@-moz-keyframes parpadeo{  
  0% { opacity: 1.0; }
  50% { opacity: 0.0; }
  100% { opacity: 1.0; }
}

@-webkit-keyframes parpadeo {  
  0% { opacity: 1.0; }
  50% { opacity: 0.0; }
   100% { opacity: 1.0; }
}

@keyframes parpadeo {  
  0% { opacity: 1.0; }
   50% { opacity: 0.0; }
  100% { opacity: 1.0; }
}
```

estaba intentando pasar a js asi:

```
window.addEventListener('load', inicio );
function inicio(){
alert("hol");
    var formulario=document.getElementById('formulario');
    formulario.addEventListener('mouseover', encima);
}
function encima(evt){

    var formulario=document.getElementById('formulario');
    formulario.style.opacity = "0.5";
}
```

pero no esta reconociendo el  `alert`

Comment: Lo siento @rn3w pero tu pregunta ahora mismo es muy amplia y tampoco está muy claro lo que realmente necesitas.

Comment: @Error404 lo modifico en un momento

Comment: A mí si que me entra en el alert: https://jsfiddle.net/2oj8cq7b/

Comment: @Error404 habia un error mas arriba en mi codigo, puse un if sin cerrar

Answer (score 6, accepted):

En el siguiente código podemos asignar y eliminar la clase `animacion` al elemento deseado.

```js
function initAnimation(){
   document.getElementById('formulario').className ='animacion';
}

function endAnimation(){
    document.getElementById('formulario').className ='';
}
```

```css
.animacion {
       /*position: absolute;*/

  animation-name: parpadeo;
  animation-duration: 1s;
  animation-timing-function: linear;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;

  -webkit-animation-name:parpadeo;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 1s;
  -webkit-animation-timing-function: linear;
  -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}

@-moz-keyframes parpadeo{  
  0% { opacity: 1.0; }
  50% { opacity: 0.0; }
  100% { opacity: 1.0; }
}

@-webkit-keyframes parpadeo {  
  0% { opacity: 1.0; }
  50% { opacity: 0.0; }
   100% { opacity: 1.0; }
}

@keyframes parpadeo {  
  0% { opacity: 1.0; }
   50% { opacity: 0.0; }
  100% { opacity: 1.0; }
}

#formulario {  
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: pink;
}
```

```html
<div id="formulario"></div>
<br>
<button onclick="initAnimation()">activar</button>
<button onclick="endAnimation()">desactivar</button>
```

El efecto lo puedes hacer también con `jQuery` si lo deseas:

```js
animacion = function(){
  
    $("#formulario").fadeTo(500, .1)
                    .fadeTo(500, 1);
}

setInterval(animacion, 1000);
```

```css
#formulario {  
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: pink;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="formulario"></div>
```

o en puro `javascript`

```js
animacion = function(){
  
  document.getElementById('formulario').classList.toggle('fade');
}

setInterval(animacion, 500);
```

```css
#formulario {  
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: pink;
  opacity:1;
  transition: opacity .5s;
}

#formulario.fade {
  opacity:0;
}
```

```html
<div id="formulario"></div>
```

Comment: lo que quise hacer fue pasar todo el codigo a js, pero creo que esto es mejor

Comment: @rn3w - te he puesto el efecto con jquery

Comment: listo solucionado.

Comment: cual es el efecto que se mueve a los costados y es usado cuando un campo requerido no esta llenado?

Comment: @rn3w - no se a que te refieres es uno de [estos](http://www.justinaguilar.com/animations/#)?

Comment: ya pregunte aca http://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/36129/mover-para-los-costados-un-div-en-una-animacion-de-3-seg ojala me deje entender