# ¿Cómo agitar elementos mediante CSS?

Tags: html, css

Pretendo mover para la izq 1 segundo y 1  segundo para la derecha, que parezca que esta temblando, cada movimiento unas 3 veces

este es mi codigo pero no hace los dos movimiento solo hace el primero

```
#formulario:hover{
   /*position: absolute;*/
  -moz-transition-property: background-color, color, left;
  -moz-transition-duration: 1s;
  -webkit-transition-property: background-color, color, left;
  -webkit-transition-duration: 1s;
  -o-transition-property: background-color, color, left;
  -o-transition-duration: 1s;
  background-color: #CEF6CE;
      left: -15px;
      right: -15px;
    position: relative;
}
```

Comment: 555 segundos son 9.25 minutos... :) podrías hacer un [jsbin.com](http://jsbin.com/?html,js,console) con tu código?

Comment: @aldanux jajaja pero no hace caso al tiempo, lo realiza directamente, apenas me ubico encima del div y ya aparece -15 a la izquierda

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Creo que el efecto que estás buscando es que se agite el elemento durante varios segundos. Esto lo puedes realizar con `keyframes`.

```css
#formulario{
  background-color: blue;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
}

#formulario:hover {
  animation: shake 0.82s;
}

@keyframes shake {
  10%, 90% {
    transform: translate3d(-1px, 0, 0);
  }
  
  20%, 80% {
    transform: translate3d(2px, 0, 0);
  }
  
  30%, 50%, 70% {
    transform: translate3d(-4px, 0, 0);
  }

  40%, 60% {
    transform: translate3d(4px, 0, 0);
  }
}
```

```html
<form id="formulario"></form>
```

Fuente: [CSS-Tricks](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/shake-css-keyframe-animation/).

---

Si no, puedes utilizar las clases que te proporcionan en esta página: https://elrumordelaluz.github.io/csshake/ mediante la cual tienes diferentes efectos para agitar tus elementos.

Simplemente tendrías que añadir el link de su css y utilizar las clases que te proporcionan en los elementos que quisieras agitar.

Ejemplo de uso:

```css
.formulario{
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://csshake.surge.sh/csshake.min.css">
<form class="formulario shake"></form>
<form class="formulario shake-hard"></form>
<form class="formulario shake-horizontal"></form>
<form class="formulario shake-crazy"></form>
```

Comment: exacto es lo que buscaba, solo se puede hacer con keyframes?

Comment: @rn3w He añadido una nueva página que te proporciona clases para realizar este efecto también. De esta manera, simplemente tendrías que añadir la clase con la que quisieras agitar al elemento correspondiente.

Comment: Como complemento a la respuesta de @Error404 también podrías utlizar la libreria llamada Animate.css https://daneden.github.io/animate.css/

Comment: @Hoose Gracias por la aportación! :)

Answer (score 3):

Posible solución en JavaScript seria realizar un timeOut recursivo que realizara las modificaciones pertinentes.
Aprovechando que la propiedad CSS transform es fácilmente scripteable, se puede hacer algo parecido a esto.
(Si no deseas hacer uso de transform, puedes usar el mismo sistema añadiendo un parseo diferente)

```js
 caja.onmouseover=function(event){shake(event.target);};
 
 function shake(elemento){
  var velocidad=32;
  var script=["translate(5px, 0px)","translate(-5px, 0px)","translate(5px, 0px)","translate(-5px, 0px)","translate(5px, 0px)"];
  script.push(""); // termina como empezó, sin transforms.
  var funcion= function(i){
   elemento.style.transform=script[i];
   i++;
   if (i<script.length)
    setTimeout(function(){funcion(i)},velocidad);
  };
  funcion(0);
 }
```

```css
 #caja {
  position:relative;
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
  background-color:blue;
 }
```

```html
<DIV id="caja"></DIV>
```

El script y la velocidad se podrian pasar también por valor y hacer la función mas genérica... o incluso incluir la velocidad en el script para indicar velocidades distintas entre frames...
Como el efecto "agitar" es rápido, no he incluido una transición, pero si quieres suavidad solo hay que añadir `elemento.style.transition=velocidad/1000+"s";` después de declarar la variable `velocidad`, pero acuérdate de quitarla luego.